# Use slash inside hash with %2F

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I'm having the following routes:

```
window.m.config( ['$routeProvider',($routeProvider) ->
  $routeProvider
  .when('/player/:index', {
    templateUrl: 'view.html',
    controller: 'View'
  })
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'list.html'
    controller: 'List'
  })
]
)
```

Some of my players have a `/` inside their name. So I am decoding it eg, for a player named `a/b`, the url to that player will be `/player/a%2Fb`

However, when I do the following, the hash will change when I load my app, so that it becomes `/player/a/b`.

This makes the page not load for that particular player.

If I put a hash with `%2F` in a non-angular app, the %2F is not transformed into / so it is not the browser that is inducing the error. However, if I then try to get the hash, I still get `/player/a/b` , where the encoded slash is === to the other slashes.

How should I handle slashes inside the variable values of my routes ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add

> *

at the end of your route. So in your case:

```
'/player/:index*'
```

That should work also with Angullar 2+. Check 
[Github issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/10479).

Answer (score 0):

I would replace/escape the slashes with underscores when creating the route argument and then re-inserting them in the controller - this way you avoid the differences.

Comment: That would be a work around, altough i could do that its not optimal, because it will either Create collisions between the player names or make the links longer

Comment: Hmm, the slashes will give problems - don't you have an integer player id you can use instead - that would be much easier :)

Answer (score 0):

So I just found this on github and wanted to provide a temporary fix, in my application I noticed it would only route on params that were double encoded so for example I used this as a temp work around:

```
encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent("this/string/is/a/param/"))
```

This seemed to work for me.